# Fetch Oracle output of dbms_output.put_line with QtSql

Tags: oracle, qt4, qtsql

Is it possible to fetch raw DB output of an Oracle DB within a QSqlQuery, e.g. by something like this:

```
QSqlQuery sqlQuery;
sqlQuery.prepare("exec dmbs_output.put_line('hello world');");
sqlQuery.exec();
```

Now I would like to access the output ('hello world' in this example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have configured the buffer that `DBMS_OUTPUT` writes to by calling `DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE` earlier, you should be able to use the [`DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#BABGBACJ) or [`GET_LINES`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#i1000253) procedure to fetch data from the buffer.

I'm not an expert with the QT libraries, but here is an example of [calling a stored procedure that returns a collection](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/9251-Accessing-array-%28TABLE-TYPE%29-in-Stored-Procedure-from-Qt) in Qt that would appear to be what you'd need to do in order to call the `GET_LINES` procedure.

Comment: When I bind a QVariant to the first parameter of GET_LINES the SQL query fails with an error message that the number of parameters of GET_LINES was not correct. Any ideas?

Comment: @fawick - `GET_LINES` takes two parameters.  The first is an array to fetch the data into.  The second is a number indicating how many lines you want to fetch.  I'm guessing you didn't pass in the second parameter?

Comment: Nope, that's okay, it's the QSqlQuery::bindValue that doesn't actually bind my QVariant...

Comment: Okay, I decided to use a different approach and abadoned Qt for this purpose. It seems like QtSql is currently not powerful enough to fetch the SQL output directly. I came to use Python and cx_oracle instead and there using "DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINES" works like charm, so this answer really helped me!